# sorting data in XML file into a dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, linq-to-xml

so i have the following xml file that my windows form gets from a website.

```
<WebserviceResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
<data xmlns="">
<ArrayOfMatches>
    <Match>
    <TimeSlot>17:00:00</TimeSlot>
    <Game_Id>18</Game_Id>
    <ArrayOfTeams>
        <Team>
            <Team_id>14</Team_id>
            <Team_Name>New Zealand</Team_Name>
            <TeamPlayers>
                <Player>
                    <PlayerId>10</PlayerId>
                    <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                    <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                </Player>
                    <Player>...</Player>
                    <Player>...</Player>
                    <Player>...</Player>
            </TeamPlayers>
        </Team>
        <Team>
            <Team_id>16</Team_id>
            <Team_Name>west indies</Team_Name>
            <TeamPlayers>...</TeamPlayers>
        </Team>
    </ArrayOfTeams>
    </Match>
</ArrayOfMatches>
</data>
```

this is just a snippet of the whole thing, the idea here is that two teams are to face eachother, which is assigned a `Game_Id`

my idea at the moment is to load the `Game_Id` `Team_Id`'s and `Team_Name`'s into a dataset all in one row, for each `Game_Id` (there are more than one games in the xml file). The team names will eventually end up in a combo box as Team1 V Team2; then when one is selected the `Player` elements will be loaded into 2 separate list boxes.

what i am able to do at the moment is fill  different datasets with `TimeSlot`& `Game_Id`, ALL the `TeamPlayers` in the xml file using `DS.ReadXML(xmlRead)`, but not the way i would like, and putting the `Game_Id`'s in a combo box with:

```
XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Match");
foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
{
     cb_matches.Items.Add(xn.InnerText);
}
```

those all work but its not what i am trying to do.

any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated, i do feel i have put as much info in here as i can.

**EDITED**

The `<Date> </Date>` only appears once per web service, there are multiple `<Game_Id>`'s on the day. It is used to make sure that the correct XML file is being used.

**EDITED**

```
<data xmlns="">
    <ArrayOfMatches>
        <Match>...</Match>
        <Match>...</Match>
    </ArrayOfMatches>
</data>
```

**EDITED**

so im still struggling more than i should with this.

```
+-----+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+
|Time |Game_Id|Team_A_Id|Team_A_Name |Team_B_Id|Team_B_Name|
|17:00|18     |14       |South Africa|16       |West Indies|
|19:00|19     |18       |New Zealand |12       |England    |
```

that's the structure i want in my `DataTable`

now i have been playing with xml-linq etc but i cant seem to lay it out like that.

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:/matchdata.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> games = xdoc.Descendants("ArrayOfMatches");

        var matches = games
            .Select(x => new Games()
            {
                GameID = x.Element("Game_Id").Value,
                TeamAID = x.Element("Team_Id").Value,
                TeamAName = x.Element("Team_Name").Value,
                TeamBID = x.Element("Team_Id").Value,
                TeamBName = x.Element("Team_Name").Value
            });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = xdoc;
```

this compiles but doesnt show any data in the `gridview` and it also doesnt show any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeSlot", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GameID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TeamAID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TeamAName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TeamBID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TeamBName", typeof(string)));

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:/matchdata.xml");
        var games = from i in xdoc.Descendants("Match")
            select new //creates a few new anonymous types to store values to dump into the datatable
        {
            TimeSlot = (string)i.Element("TimeSlot"),
            GameID = (string)i.Element("Game_Id"),
            TeamAID = (string)i.Element("ArrayOfTeams").Element("Team").Element("Team_id"),
            TeamAName = (string)i.Element("ArrayOfTeams").Element("Team").Element("Team_Name"),
            TeamBID = (string)i.Element("ArrayOfTeams").Elements("Team").Skip(1).First().Element("Team_id"), //skips a node to collect info for the next team.
            TeamBName = (string)i.Element("ArrayOfTeams").Elements("Team").Skip(1).First().Element("Team_Name") //skips a node to collect info for the next team.
        };          
        foreach (var item in games)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.TimeSlot, item.GameID, item.TeamAID, item.TeamAName, item.TeamBID, item.TeamBName); //adds a new row of data into the datatable for every <Match> </Match>
        }
```

So this works, `dt`can be made the source of a `gridview`and you can see the results. This MAY not be the best approach but at least i have learned something, comments on a better/more efficient will be looked at.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize the whole XML into an object and work with it easily
(I stripped out the first line from your xml snippet and the Match is a single entry as it's not clear where Date will go if there are multiple Matches,

```
<data>
    <ArrayOfMatches>
        <Date>2017-04-04</Date>
        <Match>
            <TimeSlot>17:00:00</TimeSlot>
            <Game_Id>18</Game_Id>
            <ArrayOfTeams>
                <Team>
                    <Team_id>14</Team_id>
                    <Team_Name>New Zealand</Team_Name>
                    <TeamPlayers>
                        <Player>
                            <PlayerId>10</PlayerId>
                            <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                            <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                        </Player>
                          <Player>
                            <PlayerId>11</PlayerId>
                            <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                            <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                        </Player>
                        <Player>
                            <PlayerId>12</PlayerId>
                            <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                            <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                        </Player> 
                    </TeamPlayers>
                </Team>
                <Team>
                    <Team_id>15</Team_id>
                    <Team_Name>New Zealand</Team_Name>
                    <TeamPlayers>
                        <Player>
                            <PlayerId>10</PlayerId>
                            <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                            <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                        </Player>
                          <Player>
                            <PlayerId>11</PlayerId>
                            <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                            <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                        </Player>
                        <Player>
                            <PlayerId>12</PlayerId>
                            <PlayerName>Trent</PlayerName>
                            <PlayerSurname>Boult</PlayerSurname>
                        </Player> 
                    </TeamPlayers>
                </Team>
            </ArrayOfTeams>
        </Match>
    </ArrayOfMatches>
</data>
```

but you should get the point)

And now you can work with `result`. 
By grabbing properties like game_id, arrays of teams, players etc.

```
    public class data
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Match[] ArrayOfMatches { get; set; }

    }

    public class ArrayOfMatches
    {

        public Match[] Match { get; set; }

    }

    public class Match
    {
        public String TimeSlot { get; set; }
        public int Game_Id { get; set; }
        public Team[] ArrayOfTeams { get; set; }
    }    

    public class Team { 
        public int Team_id { get; set; }
        public string Team_Name { get; set; }
        public Player[] TeamPlayers { get; set; }
    }   

    public class Player
    {
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public string PlayerSurname { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\input.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
                data result = (data)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: the data element is unique per web service. its just that on the day there are multiple games being played. Will give this a bash now. thanks for the reply.

Comment: date, not data. apologies if that caused any confusion.

Comment: yep, still it confuses me a bit. Can't make it work that the Date is correctly captured on ArrayOfMatches level. Can you provide me with the exact xml you get from the web?
To my understanding Date should really be either inside Match tag, or outside of the ArrayOfMatches tag

Comment: the XML code is a copy and paste from the origional, i just removed "excess data" like player names etc to make it shorter. see new edits

Comment: still your xml does not correspond to your description.
 You  write that <Date> appears once per Webservice, But XML shows it appears with each <Match>. it really seems to be improperly nested document

Comment: i dont directly have an impact, no, but i can request changes to be made. but i do agree that the nesting needs some tlc, but for the time being im going to try populate a DS with game_id, team1_id, team1_name, team2_id, team2_name.

Comment: the thing is, if you have multiple matches, you won't be able to match <Date> and <Match>. If you have multiple Game_ids - you won't be able to match <Game_id>,<ArrayOfTeams> and <TimeSlot>. <br/> Once you have <game_id><TimeSlot><ArrayOfTeams><Game_ID><TimeSlot><ArrayOfTeams> structure - all of those become unrelated. And deserializing will not work. You will have to parse it manually. Relating things by sequence.